# a{0,1}|b{0,1} matches only 'a', why?

Tags: regex, perl

Why is this happening? I've a complex regexp, but here is what is driving me crazy.

```
a|b
```

Matches either single `a` or single `b`.

```
a+|b+
```

Matches either series of `a` or series of `b`.

```
a{1}|b{1}
```

Matches both single letter the same.

But I need to do this:

```
a{0,2}|b{0,2}
```

And this regexp matches only `a` and no `b` at all. What's wrong with that?

What is even funnier is that if I change the `0` to `1`, so that it's `{1,2}`, it starts to match correctly (or better, as expected) again.

Since it seems it now quite clear, I'm adding my real example:

```
my $launch_regexp = '(\d*)d{0,1}(\d*)(\+{0,2}|-{0,2})(\d*)';
($dice, $fc, $op, $mod) = ($launch =~ /$launch_regexp/);
```

Where `$launch` is the same of `$ARGV[1]`.

I want to match many things. Examples:

```
3 (numbers)

d10 (d + numbers)

3d10 (numbers + d + numbers)

3d10+/-5 (numbers + d + numbers + (+|-) + numbers)

3d10++/--5 (numbers + d + numbers + (++|--) + numbers)
```

I know my regexp also matches other strings, but now it works with `+` and not with `-`.

If I change the range with `{1,2}`, it matches strings with both + and - (but I need to match also strings which have not such modifiers).

This is happening on my machine with Perl 5.16.3 and I'm able to reproduce it on [this website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html).

Comment: `a{0,2}` is a perfectly valid match for any string containing `b`, since it matches `b` zero times. Would you like to perhaps clarify your question by supplying input and expected output?

Comment: a{0,2} matches for 0 a's up to 1. So you might as well not have the or case as it will never reach it. You need to establish that it is to match at least 1 a or at least 1 b.

Comment: What regex engine are you using? I'm unable to reproduce your problem using a PCRE-compatible engine, or I'm misunderstanding it.

Comment: Perhaps try `a{1,2}|b{1,2}` to match the `1 or more` of `+`? You'll get the same behavior from `a*|b*`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with your regex?

Comment: @Joni, Basically, I'm trying to make an assignment. Like `my ($find) = ($string) =~ /(a{0,2}|b{0,2})`. And here is my problem. If `$string == "a"` it catch the a and assign it, if, instead, it's `"b"` it doesn't catch it. You can try it here (http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html). Enter that regexp, enter a `b` as string... not matches found.

Comment: Which is correct. What are you logically trying to achieve?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, Added some info. I can't do as you suggest, since I need to catch also strings that have not that part.

Comment: I've updated my answer, but you should probably consider that your regex with all those `*` and `{0,1}` (which could be `?`) could match a very empty looking string.

Comment: My updated answer should now match all your desired inputs.  http://regexr.com?36ldd

Comment: Please say more about what you want to do. Do you need to *verify* your data, or do you just want to separate it into fields (for which see my comment on @stevemarvell's post)? Also, is this a string *in its entirety* or are you trying to find substrings within a longer string that match this pattern?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is (a|b|)

Comment: btw, have you seen [Games::Dice](http://p3rl.org/Games::Dice)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The string "b" can be matched by the regex `a{0,2}` as it correctly has zero instances of 'a'. It won't capture, but it'll match.

In order to match '','aa' or 'bb', you want `(aa|bb)?` and to wrap your whole regex in `^` and `$`

I think what you want for your solution is: `(\d*)d?(\d+)(?:(\+{1,2}|\-{1,2})(\d*))?`

Comment: Oh yes. I didn't thought about the fact that it will match the same. But, what if I want to match `a` or `aa` or `b` or `bb` and, if none of them is found, assign my variable to an empty string? Is that possible with regexp?

Comment: I've updated to match the new info. It will match some funky other stuff, but if your input is valid, it will split it up appropriately.

Comment: @stevemarvell: That's easy to achieve: `split /(\d+)/` will do that.

Comment: that won't capture the operator @Borodin

Comment: Actually, in testing, it seems to create an empty element at the beginning of the list for those which start with numbers.

Comment: @stevemarvell: It does, but you will see a comparable effect with your regex for string that *don't* start with numbers. `$1` will be empty.

Comment: @stevemarvell, I thought it works, but actually, your regex is matching string composed by single number (like `3`) in the second group, which is not what I want. However, the question was about why the or was matching in that way, and many of you have already replied. :)

Answer (score 2):

Perl prefers earliest match in the string over anything else.  Next, it prefers the earliest of a series of `|` alternatives (not the longest, as is the case with some regex engines).
Because your first alternative can match nothing, perl will do so at the beginning of the string, for any string that doesn't start with an a.

You probably want something like:

```
my ($find) = ($string) =~ /^[^ab]*(a{1,2}|b{1,2}|\z)/;
```

Comment: unless it has following text

Comment: @stevemarvell: what happens unless what has following text?

Comment: I mean to say that if there is to be following text after this match, then `\z` in inappropriate.